# How does Leaflet handle (div)Icon anchors and divIcon size on Retina (or any HD) displays?

Tags: leaflet

## 2x Retina, or not 2x HD, that is the question.

First of all,  I don't have a Retina display to test on, and the documentation seemed a little ambiguous to me.  It is possible that the API handles things well.  It is possible that it doesn't.  It is possible that we must handle some of these things.  Either way, it is not clearly documented.

### Leaflet `Icon` object's `iconAnchor` property

For the `Icon` object, the `iconAnchor` property can be set so that the the *"tip"* is centered.  How is this handled on a Retina display, when the image is (presumably) 2x larger in each direction?  What if we can't make assumptions that every HD resolution will be 2x?  What if the HD display has a 1.75x or 2.25x larger pixel ratio?  Does Leaflet recalculate a new proportional `iconAnchor`, or do we do that manually in our load/detect/init setup, or is it a non-issue, or does it act in an undefined manner?  Should we always be required to handle something manually which perhaps belongs hidden in the API, and a more generalized resolution handling of "stretchy" Icons?

> The coordinates of the "tip" of the icon (relative to its top left corner).  The icon will be aligned so that this point is at the marker's geographical location.  Centered by default if size is specified, also can be set in CSS with negative margins. -- [Leaflet Reference: Icon.iconAnchor](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#icon-iconanchor)

### Leaflet `Icon` object

For the image-file based `Icon` object, there are the pair of properties: `iconUrl` and `iconRetinaUrl` (usually a 2x image), which are pretty self-explanatory.  Just going by the documentation and nothing else, this seems like the only reliable way to handle icon sizes on higher resolution displays.

### Leaflet `divIcon` object

Using the `DivIcon` object, we inherit the above mentioned URL properties, but we have no URLs to use, so they are not required, thus those are meaningless in this context.  We do however inherit the `iconSize` property, and this is useful for setting the size on common displays.  But there's no `IconRetinaSize`, etc.  Resolution must be detected and set manually at initialization time.  But it seems Leaflet has already done some resolution detection to some extent, with some internal code to choose between 1x and 2x image URLs based on 1x and 2x pixel ratio.  If it already has that info, why not properly handle it's own properties as well?

Answer (score 1):

Leaflet (and every JS library out there) uses CSS pixels - and the browser decides the relationship between CSS pixels and screen pixels (or "device pixels"). Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio .

The future might hold better resolution management, or maybe usage of the `<picture>` element instead of `<img>` for this. If you have any specific ideas on how to improve Leaflet, or how to improve its documentation, please do so by contributing to the project (pull requests are always welcome!)